# If form is moving then

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, mouseevent

I need to alternate the value of a boolean var.. if form is moving then MyVariable to False and if form is not moving then MyVariable to True.

I've tried this but I can click in the border of my app to move the app and then this code will not work as expected 'cause only affect if I click in the clientarea:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    Timer_Flag = False
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    Timer_Flag = True
End Sub
```

Also I've tried with move event and locationchanged... but I don't know how to detect if form is moving or not.

Comment: Will this post help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548322/winforms-window-drag-event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548322/winforms-window-drag-event

Comment: @forseta yes! thankyou so much, I just changed the handles of my example code to **ResizeBegin** and **ResizeEnd** and it works as expected. post your comment as an answer if you want free rep from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this post [WinForms window drag event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548322/winforms-window-drag-event) answered the question. Thanks Elektro Hacker, keep up the good work.